Is there any function in python-docx or a way to retrieve the hierarchy of docx file.?
i want to retrieve text based on the document section like at a particular level where multiple elements can present inside the section. enter image description here
for the example above, i should be able to retrieve the text from each Topic n where each example 1 and example 2 contents include in it. but this is sample one and i need a flexibility where i can drill through the each section by section in each topic so i can retrieve the text how ever i like.
i was trying to do this by using the styles to create such kind flexibility like either a dict or tree - (networkx), where building a tree kind of structure will provide the flexibility i need but its just im missing something.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
